# Is the following considered battle-forged?

Tags: warhammer-40k

I have recently been collecting models for my first WH40k Army, but I have yet to receive a core rule book that I have ordered. However, I do have the Space Marine book and have constructed a **Gladius Strike Force** that includes the base core requirements (1captain/chaplain, 3 tactical squads, an attack bike, and 1 devestator squad) with a handfull of auxiliary components. **If the cost of this met whatever allowance a match had, would this be considered a Battle-Forged army?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your choice really. If you take a formation you generally aren't Battle Forged (you get formation benefits instead)... However all you need to be Battle Forged is an **HQ** and two **Troops**. If your formation includes that you can choose whether to play it as Battle Forged or as the Formation.

Comment: Thanks for the vocabulary; just got the rule book today, and all **Gladius Strike Forces** include at least 1 **HQ** and 2 **Troops**

Answer (score -1):

I'm pretty sure yes. You don't need to use the main rule books Primary Detachment if you don't want to.

Comment: Welcome to Board Games Stack Exchange! Do you have anything to support your answer? It's always good to be able to cite rules and such, since someone else could just say "I'm pretty sure no" and it wouldn't be clear who would be correct.